# Conditionally return a Vue component from methods

Tags: vue.js

I have the following code:

```
Vue.component('abc', {
...
template: `
  <checkbox label="unrelated" />
  ...
  <div>{{renderTypeValue(type)}}</div>
`

methods: {
  renderTypeValue(type, val) {
    if(type === "number") return parseInt(val, 10);
    if(type === "text") return val;
    //some others...
    if(type === "checkbox") return ???
```

I'd like to return a Vue component here. I  use the same checkbox above, but I can't figure out the syntax to be able to return it from the Vue method.

Comment: If you want to return a Vue component, you should be using dynamic components, i.e. [`<component v-bind:is="...">`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) instead.

Comment: @Terry that makes sense, but I can't find any examples of template literal Vue template importing and using other (globally registered) components, they're all for SFCs.

Comment: You just import the Vue component, e.g. `import MyComponent from ...` and then you simply supply the string `MyComponent` to the `v-bind:is` directive.

Comment: @Terry I still need to import the vue component even though the component is globally registered?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and see how it goes?

Comment: @Terry this may be a basic question, but the project that I'm on doesn't have a build system (it's entirely made out of globally bound template literal components) and that means I can't do `import Foo`. When other components are used, they can just use the component in the template (i.e. the `<checkbox />` I have in the question's code, but I don't know how to refer to the same component in the component's method.